# Defining file path on freemarker.properties

Tags: struts2, freemarker

Is it possible to add a freemarker.properties file. Actually I need to include several ftl into a file by defining their directory path on freemarker.properties ? Also please tell me how to configure freemarker.properties in master ftl file since I am not using any action servlets?

Answer (score 0):

For configuring freemarker engine in struts2 all you need is to add freemarker.properties to the classpath.
The supported properties are those that the FreeMarker Configuration object expects

See this link may be it will help you

[Free Marker with Struts2](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/using-freemarker-templates.html)